# How to use custom converters with @DataMongoTest?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a test instantiating some entities, saving them to MongoDB and loading them again to make sure the mapping works corretly. I'd like to use the `@DataMongoTest` annotation on the test class to make sure an embedded  MongoDB instance is dynamically created.

This worked just fine until I had to introduce custom converters (`org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter`) for some classes. These are set up like this:

```
@ReadingConverter
public class MyClassReadConverter implements Converter<Document, MyClass> {
...

@WritingConverter
public class MyClassWriteConverter implements Converter<MyClass, Document> {
...

@Configuration
public class SpringMongoSetup extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        //I don't want that in the test..
        return new MongoClient("localhost"); 
    }

    @Override
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        // ..but I need this
        List<Converter<?,?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(new MyClassWriteConverter());
        converters.add(new MyClassReadConverter());
        return new CustomConversions(converters);
    }
...
```

For normal (non-test) execution this works just fine. The test also works if I use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation which makes the test use my configuration. Unfortunately, this configuration also defines the host/port for MongoDB, but I'd like to use the host/port of the embedded MongoDB started by `@DataMongoTest`.

Can I somehow configure it so that either `@DataMongoTest` uses the custom converters with the embedded MongoDB, or that I can get the embedded host/port while instantiating my configuration class?

Comment: To give more context to this old question - is there a way to separate connection string and mongo converters configuration? Can you have one without another during testing using possibly in-memory db? Or does it have to be integration test with a real db?

Answer (score 6):

To use `CustomConverters` with `@DataMongoTest` you need to expose those converters as a Spring bean, e.g.:

```java
@Configuration 
public class CustomConversionsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?,?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(new MyClassWriteConverter());
        converters.add(new MyClassReadConverter());
        return new CustomConversions(converters);
    }

}
```

...and use the configuration in Mongo test classes:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest
@Import(CustomConversionsConfiguration.class)
public class MyMongoTest { ... }
```

Comment: I don't know if it's because of Kotlin or a future version, but I've had to return `MongoCustomConversions` specifically for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using slicing we will disable all scanning that isn't relevant to Mongo. We have no way to know that your `SpringMongoSetup` is related to Mongo so, since we don't scan it, it's not applied.

If you do not rely on the auto-configuration for Mongo, you'll have to import that class yourself. You can do so with `@Import`, e.g.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataMongoTest
@Import(SpringMongoSetup.class)
public class MyMongoTest { ... }
```

Comment: That also uses the host/ip configured in `SpringMongoSetup`. (I omited the `@Override public Mongo mongo() {..}` part in the question, because it's mandatory for `AbstractMongoConfiguration` - I have edited it now)

How can I override that to use the embedded MongoDB launched by `@DataMongoTest`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the recommended way is (using junit5):

```
@DataMongoTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MongoConfig.class)
public class MyMongoTest { ... }
```

In your MongoConfig.class you have the configuration that your actual application uses.