# CodecConfigurationException when saving ZonedDateTime to MongoDB with Spring Boot >= 2.0.1.RELEASE

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, java-time

I was able to reproduce my problem with a minimal modification of the official Spring Boot guide for [Accessing Data with MongoDB](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/), see https://github.com/thokrae/spring-data-mongo-zoneddatetime.

After adding a `java.time.ZonedDateTime` field to the Customer class, running the example code from the guide fails with a CodecConfigurationException:

Customer.java:

```
public String lastName;
public ZonedDateTime created;

public Customer() {
```

output:

```
...
Caused by: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException`: Can't find a codec for class java.time.ZonedDateTime.
at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46) ~[bson-3.6.4.jar:na]
at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63) ~[bson-3.6.4.jar:na]
at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ChildCodecRegistry.get(ChildCodecRegistry.java:51) ~[bson-3.6.4.jar:na]
```

This can be solved by changing the Spring Boot version from 2.0.5.RELEASE to 2.0.1.RELEASE in the pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Now the exception is gone and the Customer objects including the ZonedDateTime fields [are written to MongoDB](https://github.com/thokrae/spring-data-mongo-zoneddatetime/blob/master/ZonedDateTime.png).

I filed a bug ([DATAMONGO-2106](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2106)) with the spring-data-mongodb project but would understand if changing this behaviour is not wanted nor has a high priority.

What is the best workaround? When duckduckgoing for the exception message I find several approaches like registering a [custom codec](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/bson/codecs/), a [custom converter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters) or using [Jackson JSR 310](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-jsr-310-or-java-8-new-date-apis/). I would prefer to not add custom code to my project to handle a class from the java.time package.

Comment: @cherit: My specific problem was solved by using java.time.Instant instead of ZonedDateTime. I will also post example implementations of the two workarounds (using a converter and a codec) at the beginning of the next week as an answer if nothing better comes up.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Persisting date time types with time zones was never supported by Spring Data MongoDB, as stated by Oliver Drotbohm himself in [DATAMONGO-2106](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2106?focusedCommentId=162512&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-162512).

These are the known workarounds:

1. Use a date time type without a time zone, e.g. java.time.Instant. (It is generally advisable to only use UTC in the backend, but I had to extend an existing code base which was following a different approach.)
2. Write a custom converter and register it by extending AbstractMongoConfiguration. See the branch [converter](https://github.com/thokrae/spring-data-mongo-zoneddatetime/tree/converter/src/main/java/com/github/thokrae/config) in my test repository for a running example.

   ```
   @Component
   @WritingConverter
   public class ZonedDateTimeToDocumentConverter implements Converter<ZonedDateTime, Document> {
       static final String DATE_TIME = "dateTime";
       static final String ZONE = "zone";

       @Override
       public Document convert(@Nullable ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
           if (zonedDateTime == null) return null;

           Document document = new Document();
           document.put(DATE_TIME, Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant()));
           document.put(ZONE, zonedDateTime.getZone().getId());
           document.put("offset", zonedDateTime.getOffset().toString());
           return document;
       }
   }

   @Component
   @ReadingConverter
   public class DocumentToZonedDateTimeConverter implements Converter<Document, ZonedDateTime> {

       @Override
       public ZonedDateTime convert(@Nullable Document document) {
           if (document == null) return null;

           Date dateTime = document.getDate(DATE_TIME);
           String zoneId = document.getString(ZONE);
           ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of(zoneId);

           return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(dateTime.toInstant(), zone);
       }
   }

   @Configuration
   public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

       @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
       private String database;

       @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
       private String host;

       @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
       private int port;

       @Override
       public MongoClient mongoClient() {
           return new MongoClient(host, port);
       }

       @Override
       protected String getDatabaseName() {
           return database;
       }

       @Bean
       public CustomConversions customConversions() {
           return new MongoCustomConversions(asList(
                   new ZonedDateTimeToDocumentConverter(),
                   new DocumentToZonedDateTimeConverter()
           ));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Write a custom codec. At least in theory. My [codec test branch](https://github.com/thokrae/spring-data-mongo-zoneddatetime/tree/codec/src/main/java/com/github/thokrae/config) is unable to unmarshal the data when using Spring Boot 2.0.5 while working fine with Spring Boot 2.0.1.

   ```
   public class ZonedDateTimeCodec implements Codec<ZonedDateTime> {

       public static final String DATE_TIME = "dateTime";
       public static final String ZONE = "zone";

       @Override
       public void encode(final BsonWriter writer, final ZonedDateTime value, final EncoderContext encoderContext) {
           writer.writeStartDocument();
           writer.writeDateTime(DATE_TIME, value.toInstant().getEpochSecond() * 1_000);
           writer.writeString(ZONE, value.getZone().getId());
           writer.writeEndDocument();
       }

       @Override
       public ZonedDateTime decode(final BsonReader reader, final DecoderContext decoderContext) {
           reader.readStartDocument();
           long epochSecond = reader.readDateTime(DATE_TIME);
           String zoneId = reader.readString(ZONE);
           reader.readEndDocument();

           return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond / 1_000), ZoneId.of(zoneId));
       }

       @Override
       public Class<ZonedDateTime> getEncoderClass() {
           return ZonedDateTime.class;
       }
   }

   @Configuration
   public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

       @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
       private String database;

       @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
       private String host;

       @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
       private int port;

       @Override
       public MongoClient mongoClient() {
           return new MongoClient(host + ":" + port, createOptions());
       }

       private MongoClientOptions createOptions() {
           CodecProvider pojoCodecProvider = PojoCodecProvider.builder()
                   .automatic(true)
                   .build();

           CodecRegistry registry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
                   createCustomCodecRegistry(),
                   MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                   CodecRegistries.fromProviders(pojoCodecProvider)
           );

           return MongoClientOptions.builder()
                   .codecRegistry(registry)
                   .build();
       }

       private CodecRegistry createCustomCodecRegistry() {
           return CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(
                   new ZonedDateTimeCodec()
           );
       }

       @Override
       protected String getDatabaseName() {
           return database;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Just an addition to this. If writing tests with `@DataMongoTest`, you can also [add the converter directly as an import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62458629/10543130).

Comment: To prevent UTC conversion when saving to the database and keep local date time (i.e., LocalDateTime with a separate timezone property) in Mongo database, I used the technique described by Chamindu at https://chamindu.dev/posts/localdatetime-spring-mongodb. Just make sure to extend AbstractMongoClientConfiguration instead of AbstractMongoConfiguration as he indicates. If using HTML5 form with input="datetime-local", you'll need to change the string format so DB matches what the input requires: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"