# spring data mongo can't pikup custom ZonedDateTime converter, why?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

My problem like this [CodecConfigurationException when saving ZonedDateTime to MongoDB with Spring Boot >= 2.0.1.RELEASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677253/codecconfigurationexception-when-saving-zoneddatetime-to-mongodb-with-spring-boo)

but I'm wrote a custom ZonedDateTime converters:

ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter

```java
@WritingConverter
public class ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter implements Converter<ZonedDateTime, Date> {
    @Override
    public Date convert(ZonedDateTime source) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return Date.from(source.toInstant());
    }
}
```

DateToZonedDateTimeConverter

```java
@ReadingConverter
public class DateToZonedDateTimeConverter implements Converter<Date, ZonedDateTime> {
    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convert(Date source) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(source.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    }
}
```

and my test:

```java
@Autowired
ReactiveMongoOperations operations;

@Test
void test() {
    ObjectId id = new ObjectId();

    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.append("_id", id);
//    doc.append("a", ZonedDateTime.now()); // works
    doc.append("zd1", new Document("f", ZonedDateTime.now())); // not working

    operations.insert(doc, "test-collection").block();

    Document found = Mono.from(operations.getCollection("test-collection")
            .find(new Document("_id", id)).first()).block();

    Assertions.assertNotNull(found);
}
```

if I add a ZDT instance to a first level of a document like this `doc.append("a", ZonedDateTime.now())` - document saves fine. But if I place a ZDT instance to a document as a nested field (second level of nesting) I receive an exception:

> org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.time.ZonedDateTime.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the alike problem by adding the converters to custom converters configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoCustomConverterConfig {

    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions(){
        List<Converter<?,?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(new ZoneDateTimeWriteConverter());
        converters.add(new ZonedDateTimeReadConverter());
        return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I avoided using Date or ZonedDateTime altogether and worked off of a Custom Type that wrapped LocalDateTime and used that to convert to a string for the DB. That prevents MongoDB from converting to UTC while leave the Custom Type with LocalDateTime in business level to do conversions and comparisons. You'll want to have a separate timezone property. That way you can create a new ZonedDateTime in presentation level or similar when comparing or moving to another local time. In order to do this, I used the technique described by Chamindu at [his site](https://chamindu.dev/posts/localdatetime-spring-mongodb). Just make sure to extend AbstractMongoClientConfiguration instead of AbstractMongoConfiguration as he indicates. If using HTML5 form with datetime-local (i.e., with thymeleaf: `<input type="datetime-local" th:field="*{myDate}"/>`), you'll need to change the string format from what Chamindu indicates so DB matches what the input requires. The string format that worked for me in both the HTML form and Mongo DB was. "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" instead of "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHss.SSS". Note: I am not sure how the Custom Type impacts validation and other functionality.