# upsert with MongoTemplate and use of @CreatedDate/@LastModifiedDate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a pojo which looks as following:

```
@Document
public class MyPojo {
    @Id
    private String        id;
    ...
    @CreatedDate
    private ZonedDateTime createdAt;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private ZonedDateTime modifiedAt;
}
```

I want to upsert a document with the following logic:

- if the document is new, both `createdAt` and `modifiedAt` are set to `now`.
- if the document already exists, `createdAt` should not be updated and `modifiedAt` should be set to `now`.

I tried with the following code:

```
MongoTemplate template = ...; // wired
MyPojo obj = new MyPojo();

template.findAndReplace(
        new Query().addCriteria(...),
        obj,
        new FindAndReplaceOptions().upsert());
```

Here, the members `id`, `createdAt` and `modifiedAt` are not set (hence they are `null`).

This does not seem to work. The corresponding fields in the document BSON in the database are never set.

How do you upsert a document in combination with the `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate` annotations? Is this possible, or do I need to roll out something of my own. In case of the latter, how can I achieve the upsert logic as stated above?

I am using the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing(dateTimeProviderRef = "dateTimeConverter")
```

Here, `dateTimeProviderRef` is used to support `ZonedDateTime` objects.

**Also**, I noticed that when calling `template.save(obj)` or `template.insert(obj)` instead of `findAndReplace(...)` (as in my code snippet), the `createdAt` and `modifiedAt` are set upon creation, as expected. That said, I believe I need `findAndReplace()`, because I need an atomic upsert to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the auditing by using `@EnableMongoAuditing` at your @SpringBootApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoAuditing(modifyOnCreate = false)
public class DemoApplication {
```

Also, ZonedDateTime are not supported. Please use Instant instead.

Ref:

- [CodecConfigurationException when saving ZonedDateTime to MongoDB with Spring Boot >= 2.0.1.RELEASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677253/codecconfigurationexception-when-saving-zoneddatetime-to-mongodb-with-spring-boo)
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10743

See this working example:

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.EnableMongoAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.FindAndReplaceOptions;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.time.Instant;

import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query.query;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class Ctrl {
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate template;

    @GetMapping("/templ")
    void templ() throws InterruptedException {
        template.insert(new MyPojo("TOM"));
        template.insert(new MyPojo("HARRY"));


        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //update BOB to Robert if exists or insert new
        //should inert new
        template.findAndReplace(
                query(where("name").is("BOB")),
                new MyPojo("Robert"),
                new FindAndReplaceOptions().upsert());


        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //update TOM to Tommy if exists or insert new
        template.findAndReplace(
                query(where("name").is("TOM")),
                new MyPojo("Tommy"),
                new FindAndReplaceOptions().upsert());


        template.findAll(MyPojo.class).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

@Document
@Data
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
class MyPojo {
    public MyPojo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    private String id;
    String name = "";
    @CreatedDate
    private Instant createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Instant modifiedAt;
}
```

Output:

```
MyPojo(id=5f736d33b72165754ea9fca1, name=Tommy, createdAt=2020-09-29T17:21:59.765Z, modifiedAt=null)
MyPojo(id=5f736d33b72165754ea9fca2, name=HARRY, createdAt=2020-09-29T17:21:55.732Z, modifiedAt=null)
MyPojo(id=5f736d352e78c143350ed0f8, name=Robert, createdAt=2020-09-29T17:21:57.748Z, modifiedAt=null)
```

Comment: I have examined your update. I will have to investigate what's the difference with my case. However, do you have an idea why `modifiedAt` is still `null` for `Tommy` in your code snippet? It looks like `findAndReplace()` is just updating the non-`null` fields, which conflicts with the expected behavior of `@LastModifiedDate`.

Comment: If you alter your initial two `insert()` operations with a `findAndReplace()` in your code snippet, you will also notice that `createdAt` is not filled in.